# php form email not displaying html

Tags: php, html, forms, email, web

I develop my own site for my photography business. I use php for my Pre-Wedding questionnaire form emails. It has worked fine for me so far. However, to make it more convenient for me to read and use, I want the email to put data in an html table format. The html code works when tested but the emails only display the code. Can someone help find why this will not work for me. Thanks.

```
<?php

$howDidYouHear = $_POST['howDidYouHear'];
$weddingDate = $_POST['weddingDate'];
$weddingTime = $_POST['weddingTime'];
$ceremonyLocation = $_POST['ceremonyLocation'];
$receptionLocation = $_POST['receptionLocation'];
$additionalLocation = $_POST['additionalLocation'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$brideName = $_POST['brideName'];
$brideCell = $_POST['brideCell'];
$brideEmail = $_POST['brideEmail'];
$brideAddress = $_POST['brideAddress'];
$bridesMaidsNum = $_POST['bridesMaidsNum'];
$bridesMaidsNames = $_POST['bridesMaidsNames'];
$bridePrep = $_POST['bridePrep'];
$groomName = $_POST['groomName'];
$groomCell = $_POST['groomCell'];
$groomEmail = $_POST['groomEmail'];
$groomAddress = $_POST['groomAddress'];
$groomsmenNum = $_POST['groomsmenNum'];
$groomsmenNames = $_POST['groomsmenNames'];
$groomPrep = $_POST['groomPrep'];
$maidOfHonor = $_POST['maidOfHonor'];
$bestMan = $_POST['bestMan'];
$brideParents = $_POST['brideParents'];
$groomParents = $_POST['groomParents'];
$flowerGirl = $_POST['flowerGirl'];
$ringBearer = $_POST['ringBearer'];
$setting = $_POST['setting'];
$restrictions = $_POST['restrictions'];
$details = $_POST['details'];
$emotions = $_POST['emotions'];
$shootType = $_POST['shootType'];
$familyPhotos = $_POST['familyPhotos'];
$knowFirstLook = $_POST['knowFirstLook'];
$firstLook = $_POST['firstLook'];
$importantPhotos = $_POST['importantPhotos'];
$incorporate = $_POST['incorporate'];

$email_from = 'info@example.com';
$email_subject = "Pre-Wedding Questionaire Form";
$email_body = 

$message = 
    '<table width="600px" cellpadding="2" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid black">
        <tr><td colspan="4" style="background:black; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:18px;">Pre-Wedding Questionnaire</td></tr>
        <tr><th colspan="3"  style="font-size:16px;">$brideName and $groomName</th><th width="25%" style="font-size:16px;">$weddingDate</th></tr>
        <tr><td width="25%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">How did you hear:</td><td colspan="3">$howDidYouHear</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Wedding Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Date of Wedding:</td><td colspan="3">$weddingDate</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Time of Wedding:</td><td colspan="3">$weddingTime</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Ceremony:</td><td colspan="3">$ceremonyLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Reception:</td><td colspan="3">$receptionLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Additional Location:</td><td colspan="3">$additionalLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Guests:</td><td colspan="3">$guests</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Bride Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Name:</td><td colspan="3">$brideName</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Cell:</td><td colspan="3">$brideCell</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Email:</td><td colspan="3">$brideEmail</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Address:</td><td colspan="3">$brideAddress</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Bridesmaids:</td><td colspan="3">$bridesMaidsNum</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Names of Bridesmaids:</td><td colspan="3">$bridesMaidsNames</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Bride Prep:</td><td colspan="3">$bridePrep</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Groom Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Name:</td><td colspan="3">$groomName</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Cell:</td><td colspan="3">$groomCell</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Email:</td><td colspan="3">$groomEmail</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Address:</td><td colspan="3">$groomAddress</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Groomsmen:</td><td colspan="3">$groomsmenNum</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Names of Groomsmen:</td><td colspan="3">$groomsmenNames</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Groom Prep:</td><td colspan="3">$groomPrep</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Key Names~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Maid of Honor:</td><td colspan="3">$maidOfHonor</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Best Man:</td><td colspan="3">$bestMan</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Parents:</td><td colspan="3">$brideParents</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Parents:</td><td colspan="3">$groomParents</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Flower Girl:</td><td colspan="3">$flowerGirl</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ring Bearer:</td><td colspan="3">$ringBearer</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Key Details~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ceremony Setting:</td><td colspan="3">$settings</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ceremony Restrictions:</td><td colspan="3">$restrictions</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Details:</td><td colspan="3">$details</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">3 Emotions:</td><td colspan="3">$emotions</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Shoot Type:</td><td colspan="3">$shootType</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Family Photos:</td><td colspan="3">$familyPhotos</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Do you know what a first look is:</td><td colspan="3">$knowFirstLook</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Will There Be a First Look:</td><td colspan="3">$firstLook</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Important Photos:</td><td colspan="3">$importantPhotos</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">What to incorporate:</td><td colspan="3">$incorporate</td></tr>
    </table>';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$to = "me@example.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header('Location: http://www.example.com/faq/index.html');

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you use phpmailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for best result

Comment: Your PHP variables won't be interpreted because they're within single-quotes instead of double-quotes.